# Editing vector layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

I wish to edit and remove qgsfeatures in qgsvectorlayer. Vectorlayer contains postgis table.

QgsVectorDataProvider::capabilitiesString() returns the folowing string:
Add Features, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Fast Access to Features at ID, Simplify Geometries, Simplify Geometries with topological validation

So it looks like I can only add new features, not edit/delete already created.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the attribute table for this, where you can see all the data inside the table you´ve added. See [here for a detailed introduction](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2010/10/working-with-attribute-table-basic.html). At its bottom you see a marker-symbol which you may use to edit the data.

Comment: I have no rights to edit postgis table nor from qgis main view, nor from attribute table, nor from c++ code. It looks like the problem in postgis database rights. But i have no ideas how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete features if you know their ID by loading the layer into canvas from the DB Manager:

[image: DB Manager]

Then from the **Python Console**, you can use:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Then from the *DB Manager > Table*, select the **Run Vacuum Analyze** tool to update the data table:

[image: Vacuum]

You should then see your list of rows updated:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like i've found the answer to my question.

Postgres tables generated with osm2pgsql don't have a primary key. Postgis fails to edit/delete rows in such tables, but alows to add new rows.

Adding primary key to my table solved problem.

Comment: seeing this issue a lot lately...